# WP_Query and next_posts_link

Tags: wp-query, navigation, loop

I cannot figure out how to make next_posts_link() work within my custom WP_Query. Here is the function:

```
function artists() {
  echo '<div id="artists">';
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'artist', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => get_query_var( 'page' ));
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<a class="artist" href="'.get_post_permalink().'">';
    echo '<h3 class="artist-name">'.get_the_title().'</h3>';
    $attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
    $total_attachments = count( $attachments );
    for( $i=0; $i<$total_attachments; $i++ ) {
      $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachments[$i]['id'], 'thumbnail' );
      echo '<span class="thumb"><img src="'.$thumb[0].'" /></span>';
    }
    echo '</a>';
  endwhile;
  echo '</div>';
  next_posts_link();
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try passing max_num_pages to the function:

```
next_posts_link('Older Entries »', $loop->max_num_pages);
```

Answer (score 10):

`next_posts_link` and `previous_posts_link` , as well as several others functions, make use of a global variable called `$wp_query`. This variable is actually an instance of the WP_Query object. However, when you create our own instantiation of WP_Query, you don’t have this global variable `$wp_query`, which is why paging will not work.

to fix that you trick `$wp_query` global

```
//save old query
$temp = $wp_query; 
//clear $wp_query; 
$wp_query= null; 
//create a new instance
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'artist', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => get_query_var( 'page' ));
$wp_query->query($args);
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
    echo '<a class="artist" href="'.get_post_permalink().'">';
    echo '<h3 class="artist-name">'.get_the_title().'</h3>';
    $attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
    $total_attachments = count( $attachments );
    for( $i=0; $i<$total_attachments; $i++ ) {
      $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachments[$i]['id'], 'thumbnail' );
      echo '<span class="thumb"><img src="'.$thumb[0].'" /></span>';
    }
    echo '</a>';
  endwhile;
  echo '</div>';
  next_posts_link();
//clear again
$wp_query = null; 
//reset
$wp_query = $temp;
```