# Pagination problem by using WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, pagination

Sorry for me, if I use incorrect words or sentenses, my English is poor, i.e. I'm from Russia.
I have problem with pagination by using WP_query and pagination links like next_posts_link and previous_posts_link. My permalinks set is /%category%/%postname%/. WP 3.3.1.
There is my code:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 0;
$looks = new WP_Query('cat=3&posts_per_page=4&paged='.$paged);
while ($looks->have_posts()) : $looks->the_post(); ?>

    <ul class="look">
    <a class="look_thumb" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
    </a>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    </ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php next_posts_link('<small class="page_navi">Другие записи >></small>'); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link('<small class="page_navi">Предыдущие записи <<</small>'); ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

next_posts_link and previous_posts_link don't apear on page. This custom loop from my template page: 'looks_page.php'.
What's wrong!? I'm trying fix it problem by during 3 days, but no results :(.

Comment: see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20424/wp-query-and-next-posts-link

Comment: sorry, but all of your suggestions don't work.

Comment: if neither of those work, then you've made an error in implementing them. what that error may be I can't say without seeing the code you've tried.

Comment: http://www65.zippyshare.com/v/65980174/file.html

Comment: `$loop->max_num_pages` should in your case be `$looks->max_num_pages`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the wrong query_var.  It should be 'paged'

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 0;
```

Comment: Also, make sure you have at least 5 posts in your category.

Comment: `page` is correct. see [Pagination Note on WP_Query codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

Comment: WP Codex:Pagination Note: You should set get_query_var( 'page' ); if you want your query to work with pagination. Since Wordpress 3.0.2, you do get_query_var( 'page' ) instead of get_query_var( 'paged' ). The pagination parameter 'paged' for WP_Query() remains the same.