# Add AJAX "Load more" on custom query block

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, ajax, buddypress

I have a `index,php` with various `new WP_Query` all working ok, but in this block I need to implement that "AJAX thing people love - the load more posts":

```
   <h2>Latests articles <?php bp_site_name(); ?></h2>

   <?php
   $destaque = get_term_by('slug', 'destaque', 'post_tag');
   $video = get_term_by('slug', 'video', 'post_tag');

   $nd_query = new WP_Query (array('tag__not_in' => array($destaque->term_id, $video->term_id), 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' =>$paged));
   while ($nd_query->have_posts()) : $nd_query->the_post(); ?>

   <span class="box-excerpt" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
   <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
   </span>

   <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Tought this was simple but I can't even figure out how to set a pagination in this block. If there's anything than AJAX let me know.

**NOte!**
I'm modifying an BuddyPress theme, that came with some AJAX, maybe is there smeway to re-use things.

Comment: I found a excelent tipo from Scribu now the pagination works: http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/wpn-2-74.html I think I'm halfway on the AJAX thing.

Comment: Do I have to do this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20424/wp-query-and-next-posts-link in order to implement AJAX?! Tough wp_paginavi works that I would assume that AJAX would too :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial that Michael Martin posted on Pro Blog Design should help you: http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/

Comment: Thanks Pippin, but my issue is: I don't have any pagination, this is just a block using `new WP_Query` most examples deal with the main query.

Comment: Database Error... Seems no longer available as of 7/11/2021